# How to combine a list of the prime factors?

Tags: prime-numbers

As a simple example, there is a list of prime factors.

```
{{2, 1}, {3, 2}, {43, 5}, {26684839, 1}}
```

How to combine them to the number `70612139395722186` using *Mathematica*?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Times @@ Power @@@ {{2, 1}, {3, 2}, {43, 5}, {26684839, 1}}
```

Comment: The docs display [something similar](http://wolfram.com/xid/0enx9tara-bw2).

Answer (score 4):

```
Times @@ (#[[1]]^#[[2]] & /@ {{2, 1}, {3, 2}, {43, 5}, {26684839, 1}})
```

Answer (score 4):

Also

```
pf = {{2, 1}, {3, 2}, {43, 5}, {26684839, 1}};

Inner[Power, ## & @@ (pf\[Transpose]), Times]
(* 70612139395722186 *)
```

Comment: Equivalently, `Inner[Power, pf[[All, 1]], pf[[All, 2]], Times]`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another one

```
primefactors = {{2, 1}, {3, 2}, {43, 5}, {26684839, 1}};

Fold[Times[#1, Power @@ #2] &, 1, primefactors]
```

> 70612139395722186

If the list gets larger enough, you can use `ParallelCombine` to MapReduce it,

```
ParallelCombine[Fold[Times[#1, Power @@ #2] &, 1, #]&, primefactors, Times]
```

For the list of current size, this actually only slows it down. And it can be used with any of the methods show here so far. If the method does it with as a function, f[#]& then:

```
 ParallelCombine[f[#]&, primefactors, Times]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Table[#1, #2] & @@@ lis // Map[Apply[Sequence]] // Apply[Times]
```

or

```
Times @@ (Sequence @@ Table[#1, #2] & @@@ lis)
```

or

```
Times @@ (Times @@ Table[#1, #2] & @@@ lis)
```

or

```
lis /. {a_, b_} :> a^b // Times @@ # &
```

---

*Result:*

> 70612139395722186

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{2, 1}, {3, 2}, {43, 5}, {26684839, 1}};
```

Two slot-free variants of Syed's solution:

Using `Splice` (new in 12.1)

```
Times @@ Splice @* Table @@@ list
```

70612139395722186

Using `MapApply` (new in 13.1)

```
Times @@ Flatten @ MapApply[Table] @ list
```

70612139395722186

Comment: For older versions not featuring `MapApply`: `Times @@ Flatten@Map[Apply[Table]]@list`